# Uno Platform Missing emulator list in debug targets for SDK style projects

Tags: android, android-emulator, uno-platform

Having

- latest Uno templates,
- all green uno-check,
- latest VS 2022 preview (17.4.0 Preview 1.0).

Creating new Uno app (either via commandline or selecting from the new project wizard) including `Android` head - which is the new SDK style project, I'm unable to start the app in an emulator. It's missing and the VS complains either of:

- `Please select a valid device before running the application.`
- ```
    ----------------------------
    Microsoft Visual Studio
    ---------------------------
    Unable to start debugging. The startup project cannot be launched. Ensure that the correct project is set as the startup project. The startup project can be changed by selecting the 'Set as Startup Project' command from the right click menu in Solution Explorer.

    Additionally make sure its debug settings are correctly configured in project properties.
    ---------------------------
    OK   
    ---------------------------
  ```

When using the old non SDK style Android project, e.g. from [Uno.Samples](https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Samples/tree/master/UI/AndroidCustomCamera), on the same setup, it won't compile though (until `<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>` is added to the `.csproj` file). Anyway, after that, the list of emulators is available and the project can be started on a selected emulator.

**Is there any magic I could do on the new SDK style project to have list of emulators to debug the app on?**

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an issue in the Visual Studio itself (no relation to Uno). Using 17.3.1 release (not preview):

- shows the emulators,
- creates some changes in the project upon load (`.vs` binary content also as new `<proj-name>.user` file),
- allows the project to run.

Interestingly enough, such modified project then works also in preview (although the emulators are still not listed explicitly), even after the `.user` file is deleted.